# MenuItem Icon not clickable? WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a menuitem that contains a sub menu of menuitems. For some reason, to set off the command i have to click the actual menuitem and not the menuitem icon as well. i.e. clicking the menuitem icon doesn't trigger the command. Here is my XAML. Is there any easy fix for this as i want to be able to click both the text and the icon for the command to run.

```
<MenuItem Header="Choose Shoe Colour"
        ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.ShoeModels, Source={x:Reference sItemControl}}"
        Command="{Binding DataContext.ChooseShoe_Click, Source={x:Reference sItemControl}}">
                                                <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <MenuItem Header="{Binding ShoeColour}"
                                                                  Command="{Binding DataContext.ChooseShoe_Click, Source={x:Reference sItemControl}}"
                                                                  CommandParameter="{Binding ShoeId}">
                                                            <MenuItem.Icon>
                                                                <Ellipse Fill="{Binding ShoeId, Converter={StaticResource ShoeIdToColorConverter}}"/>
                                                            </MenuItem.Icon>
                                                        </MenuItem>
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                                            </MenuItem>
```

Comment: downvote reason?

Comment: Maybe because your issue is not [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You can't click on a menuitem's icon and get a command response. That's by design, so I'm wondering if there is a way around it. Or even, I can see that the menuitem's header does not take all the space in the column to click, so you can click on the right side and it won't trigger anything

Comment: Add attribute " Click="menuEditSettings_Click" "